# The motion of a ball thrown in a rotating frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

Assume, there are 2 people staying next to each other on a rotating disk, s.t. there is a straight line from one to the other going through the center of the disk. One throws a ball to the other.

I want to discribe the motion of the ball relative to the person, who threw it:

Let $\vec{r_p}$ be the position of the person and $\vec{r_b}$ be the position of the ball, relative to the rotation axis.

Then, the position of the ball, relative to the person $\vec{r}^p_{b} = \vec{r_b} - \vec{r_p}$. Therefore, the relative velocity is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}^p_{b} = \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r_b} - \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r_p} = \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r_b} - \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_p}
$$
and the acceleration
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{r}^p_{b} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{r_b} - \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_p} - \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_p)
$$

Now, the question is, why am I losing the coriolis term here (i.e. where and why did it go wrong)?

Comment: Are you using the transport theorem as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame#Time_derivatives_in_the_two_frames)? If so, you need to distinguish in your equations a time derivative that's taken in the rotating frame vs. the one in the inertial frame. Also, it looks like the Coriolis term is very much present (are you just missing parentheses when differentiating one of the terms??)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Amit. I didn't take the time derivative properly.

Answer (score 0):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
The equations

\begin{align*}
  & u=  r_b- r_p\quad\text{vector $~u~$  rotate with }~\omega\,t\\
  &0=\dot{r}_b+\omega\times\,r_b-\dot{r}_p-\omega\times\,r_p=
  \dot r'+\omega\times r'\\
  &0= \ddot r'+\underbrace{\omega\times\dot r'+\omega\times \dot r'}_{2\,(\omega\times v')}+\omega\times(\omega\times r')
\end{align*}

you obtain

\begin{align*}
 &\ddot{r}'=-2\,(\omega\times\,v')-\omega\times(\omega\times r')
\end{align*}